# Still uncleared on the dex format

Tags: android, file-format, dex

I had read the .dex format document on Google, but I still got some confuses with some layer.

link_size & link_off : Google said it left unspecified and then said it's hook for runtime, so what it is? The static hook for global or local? or the hook to native library?

map_off : Why it need this redundancy IDs list? is it some kinda like the file address table?

proto_size & proto_off : Not quite sure what it actually is. I had de-assembled an randomly picked dex and look on this section, this section contained some short sign like DD/LL/JLJJ/...brabrabra, that made me more confused about this section. What exactly this section doing for?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Another question: where the dex contains the native library(.so)?

Comment: It doesn't. They are stored in the apk, or, in places like /system/lib.

Comment: That does cleared alot fog for me, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link section has never been specified or used. You might run across some dex files that have a garbage value for these fields, as an attempt to prevent baksmali from being able to be run on them (due to an old bug, that has been fixed for a while).

For the map item, Yes, there is redundancy for the locations of the indexed item sections - the location for these are specified in both the header item and the map item. But the map item is the only place the locations of the offset item sections are specified (the variable size items in the data section)

The prototype section defines the prototype for a method, i.e. the parameters and return type. If you look in the method_id_item, you'll see that it has a reference to a prototype item.

Comment: As a bit of flavor on the map and the header: You can walk the header (of a valid dex file) to get to any item you need to when running the file. However, the only sensible way to iterate over all the contents of a dex file is to use the map. For example, the map is what's used when doing structural validation/verification of a dex file.

Comment: I wouldn't say that a proto is an "appended together" list of types (though if you compare them to the equivalent in a .class file, that's kinda what it may seem like). Protos are intentionally structured, so that the vm doesn't have to parse out the individual types as strings (unlike .class files). Also, a proto includes a return type in addition to the list of argument types.

Comment: danfuzz: oops! I was confusing what was in proto_id_item. For some reason I was thinking it was just a string reference to the prototype string. durrr :)